# How to extract all Links from Bing? (How to declare variables inside a Scrapy class?)

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, screen-scraping, scrapy

I need to extract the links in the search results of the Bing search ([url](http://'https://www.bing.com/search?q=Brexit&filters=ex1%3A%22ez5_15706_16976%22&qpvt=Brexit')).

`page_links` is supposed to hold the URLs of the other pages in the Bing search available at the bottom of the page.

`news_link_list` is supposed to hold the URLs of all the news website stories that I want to track (decided by `legal_domains`)

The `yield Request(url, callback)` was supposed loop through all the `page_links` and get the `response` then do the manipulations to update `news_linked_list` and `verified_links`.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.http import Request
import re


class LinksSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'links'
    verified_links = []
    news_link_list = []
    legal_domains = [
                 'www.bloomberg.com',
                 'www.bbc.com',
                 'www.theguardian.com',
                 'www.cnn.com',
                 'www.foxnews.com',
                 'www.breitbart.com'
    ]
    legal_domains.sort()
    start_urls = ['https://www.bing.com/search?q=Brexit&filters=ex1%3a%22ez5_15706_16976%22&qpvt=Brexit']

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.css("a::attr(href)").extract()
        last_index = len(links) - 1
        for i in range(last_index, -1, -1):
            if links[i] == '#':
                last_index =  i
        page_links = links[last_index:]
        filtered_links = []
        for each_link in links:
            filtered_links = filtered_links + re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', each_link)
        filtered_links.sort()

        for each_news_url in filtered_links:
            for each_domain in legal_domains:
                if each_domain in each_news_url and each_news_url not in news_link_list:
                    with open('news_link_list', 'a') as f:
                        f.write(each_news_url)
                    news_link_list.append(each_news_url)
                    break
        verified_links = verified_links + page_links
        for each_page_url in page_links:
            yield Request(url=each_page_url, callback="parse")
```

But I got the following error (variable not defined) but it has been so I wanted to know if this is because of the way `scrapy` works and if it is then **how do I fix it?**.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dennis/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/home/dennis/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/home/dennis/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 339, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/home/dennis/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/home/dennis/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/home/dennis/tutorial/tutorial/spiders/links.py", line 35, in parse
    for each_domain in legal_domains:
NameError: name 'legal_domains' is not defined
```

*I am new to Scrapy so please pardon me if this is straightforward. I am sure this would help other early adopters of Scrapy*

Answer (score 1):

Change `for each_domain in legal_domains:` to `for each_domain in self.legal_domains:`

Answer (score 0):

Add self to all the variable you declared in class ( LinksSpider ) as follows:

```
def parse(self, response):
    links = response.css("a::attr(href)").extract()
    last_index = len(links) - 1
    for i in range(last_index, -1, -1):
        if links[i] == '#':
            last_index =  i
    page_links = links[last_index:]
    filtered_links = []
    for each_link in links:
        filtered_links = filtered_links + re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', each_link)
    filtered_links.sort()

    for each_news_url in filtered_links:
        for each_domain in self.legal_domains:
            if each_domain in each_news_url and each_news_url not in self.news_link_lists:
                with open('news_link_list', 'a') as f:
                    f.write(each_news_url)
                self.news_link_list.append(each_news_url)
                break
    verified_links = self.verified_links + page_links
    for each_page_url in page_links:
        yield Request(url=each_page_url, callback="parse")
```